# Error - "..for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 8"

Tags: mysql

So I'm just doing a basic create table script but I cannot, for the life of me, find out where it's erroring out. Here's the script (the format was a little wonky):

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    custID int,
    first varchar(30),
    last varchar(30),
    email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT custID_PK PRIMARY KEY(custID),
    CONSTRAINT email_ck CHECK (email LIKE '%_@__%.__%'),
    CONSTRAINT email_uq UNIQUE(email);
)
```

Help!

Comment: remove the `;` at the end of your last constraint.

Comment: By the way that's not a very good email address validator. There's no requirement that there's a `.` the domain part. The new gTLDs are under no obligation to use a subdomain. `.google` and `.microsoft` are both TLDs now. The only way to figure out if it's valid is to try and deliver to it. Also, 50 characters is way too strict. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default unless you have other more compelling reasons to shorten that.

Comment: And `__%.__%` will reject some perfectly valid domains, like "t.co". Advice: Don't do validation in the database. Do that in the application.

Comment: Also, since noone mentioned it before, be aware that MySQL doesn't support `check` constraints. You can use them in your code for compatibility reasons, but they are completely ignored and won't check anything.